# Can't edit/add a specific content type sometimes - SQL has gone away

Tags: nodes, database

Hi Can anyone help with this situation.

I am on Drupal 7.12 and I am getting a white page (or if I have enabled errors to show, a SQL has gone away error when I try to add or edit a specific content type:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT rid, permission FROM {role_permission} WHERE rid IN (:fetch_0); Array ( [:fetch_0] => 1 ) in user_role_permissions() (line 752 of /var/www/vhosts/pen.org/staging.pen.org/modules/user/user.module).

This only happens sometimes and when it does lasts a couple of days. And it goes away suddenly. During the time it happens, other content types are editable. The site also functions fine.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any insight is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this and action as soon as you possibly can: https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005. In the meantime, you may want to remove the URL to your site from your question